# How can I prevent code duplication in this Verilog 2001 address decoder?

Tags: fpga, verilog

I'm just getting more familiar with Verilog 2001 and I'm writing an AXI4-Lite core for the first time.

I have an address decoder case statement that defines a series of registers that can be read/written to by a 32-bit AXI4-Lite master. For the larger regions, I specify an address base and a size in bytes as parameters and then decode the address with a `for` loop.

I'm not particularly happy about this HDL structure as it feels like I have to duplicate the same logic over and over. I'm hoping for a more readable and concise way to describe this same concept of writing 32-bit blocks to internal registers.

This is intended to synthesize for an FPGA.

```
    case(address)
        ADDR_VERSION: begin
        end
        ADDR_CONTROL: begin
            control_reg <= data;
        end
        default: begin

            // The following memory mapped writes will write 32-bits from low
            // AXI addresses to the MSB of the register, and high addresses to
            // the LSB.

            // Key decoder
            for (integer i = 0; i < SIZE_KEY/4; i = i + 1) begin
                if (address == (ADDR_KEY + i*4)) begin
                    key_reg[32*(SIZE_KEY/4-1-i) +: 32] <= data;
                end
            end

            // IV decoder
            for (integer i = 0; i < SIZE_IV/4; i = i + 1) begin
                if (address == (ADDR_IV + i*4)) begin
                    iv_reg[32*(SIZE_IV/4-1-i) +: 32] <= data;
                end
            end
        end
    endcase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [for-if antipattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/371133/for-if-antipattern) to avoid writing the closed form of the address calculation:

```vhdl
if(address >= ADDR_IV && address < ADDR_IV + SIZE_IV && address % 4 == 0)
    iv_reg[32*(SIZE_IV/4-1-(address-ADDR_IV)/4) +: 32] <= data;
end
```

This can be simplified a lot:

```vhdl
if(address >= ADDR_IV && address < ADDR_IV + SIZE_IV && address % 4 == 0)
    iv_reg[8*SIZE_IV - 8*(address - ADDR_IV) - 32 +: 32] <= data;
end
```

This is still ugly, but you can build a stack of functions to make it more readable (untested, and I'm not a Verilog programmer at all, but you should get the idea and be able to improve on it, e.g. by giving names to constants):

```vhdl
function matches;
    input [31:0] address, BASE, SIZE;
    begin
        if(address % 4 != 0)
            // unaligned
            matches = false;
        else if(address < BASE)
            matches = false;
        else if(address < BASE + SIZE)
            matches = true;
        else
            matches = false;
    end
endfunction

function integer range_bottom;
    input [31:0] address, BASE, SIZE;
    begin
        range_bottom = 8*SIZE - 8*(address - BASE) - 32;
    end
endfunction

...

if(matches(address, ADDR_IV, SIZE_IV))
    iv_reg[range_bottom(address, ADDR_IV, SIZE_IV) +: 32] <= data;
end
```

From a synthesis perspective, if you align the addresses of the "long" registers to their size, the calculations decay to bit masks and shifts, that saves quite a bit of logic resources.

The constants in the example are chosen so you can see what is going on:

- 64 is SIZE_IV (so a 512 bit IV)
- 128 is ADDR_IV (a multiple of 64)
- 32 is BUS_WIDTH
- 8 is BITS_PER_BYTE
- 512 is SIZE_IV * BITS_PER_BYTE
- 4 is BUS_WIDTH / BITS_PER_BYTE
- 6 is log2(SIZE_IV)
- 5 is log2(BUS_WIDTH)
- 3 is log2(BITS_PER_BYTE)
- 2 is log2(BUS_WIDTH/BITS_PER_BYTE)
- (*x*-1) are bitmasks generated from *x*

Now, constants are inserted into the code:

```vhdl
if(address >= 128 && address < 128 + 64 && address % 4 == 0)
    iv_reg[512 - 8*(address - 128) - 32 +: 32] <= data;
end
```

During synthesis, the compiler would transform

- range comparison to bitwise AND and equality
- modulus to bitwise AND
- subtraction to bitwise AND
- multiplication to bit shift

Paraphrased as Verilog (in reality, these substitutions would be done on the RTL):

```vhdl
if(address & ~(64-1) == 128 && address & (4-1) == 0)
    iv_reg[512 - ((address & (64-1)) << 3) - 32 +: 32] <= data;
end
```

- pull in `address[1:0] == 0` from the outer condition as a constant into the index calculation
- reduce bitmasks to slices
- replace twos'-complement minus with ones' complement and addition

```vhdl
if(address[:6] == 128>>6 && address[1:0] == 0)
    iv_reg[512 + ((~address[6-1:2] + 1) << 5) - 32 +: 32] <= data;
end
```

- pull the `(1 << 5)` out as `32`
- addition and subtraction now cancel out

```vhdl
if(address[:6] == 128>>6 && address[1:0] == 0)
    iv_reg[(~address[5:2]) << 5 +: 32] <= data;
end
```

... and we've reached a state that should synthesize quite well. I've replaced `6-1` by `5` in the last fragment, to make it more obvious that the address is sliced into three parts:

- `[:6]` addresses `iv_reg`
- `[5:2]` addresses a subrange of `iv_reg`
- `[1:0]` must be zero

Again, these are RTL transformations (so explaining them using Verilog is wrong) that happen whenever the compiler can prove that some bit will always be constant, so the subtraction will always reduce to some partial form where only the relevant bits are calculated, but it will disappear completely only if the register addresses are aligned to their size.

Comment: Awesome, this is really insightful thank you. As a software developer by trade, it continues to be extremely difficult for me to think in terms of digital design having not grown up studying the basic structures. I'll continue to work more to visualize in terms of RTL!

Comment: In your example, I think `range_bottom` will need a storage specifier for its output otherwise it will default to a single bit.

Like: `function integer range_bottom;`

Comment: @Gbps, indeed, it needs a storage specifier.

Comment: @Gbps, the refactoring to make it more readable is the same as I'd do for software (the question I linked is a C# question after all). The RTL thinking only comes in later, for optimizing the design for minimal resource use and higher speed -- and, like with software, designing a better algorithm will make the code less readable.